# REGR_SLOPE in Teradata SQL Query Returning 0 Slope

Tags: sql, teradata, linear-regression

I am a relative newbie with Teradata SQL and have run into this strange (I think strange) situation. I am trying to run a regression (REGR_SLOPE) on sensor data. I am gathering sensor readings for a single day, each day is 80 observations which is confirmed by the COUNT in the outer SELECT. My query is:

```
 SELECT
  d.meter_id,
  REGR_SLOPE(d.reading_measure, d.x_axis) AS slope,
  COUNT(d.x_axis) AS xcount,
  COUNT(d.reading_measure) AS read_count
  FROM
  (
  SELECT
      meter_id,
      reading_measure,
      row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Reading_Dttm) AS x_axis
  FROM data_mart.v_meter_reading
  WHERE Reading_Start_Dt = '2017-12-12'

  AND Meter_Id IN (11932101, 11419827, 11385229, 11643466)

  AND Channel_Num = 5
  ) d
  GROUP BY 1
```

When I use the "IN" clause in the subquery to specify Meter_Id, I get slope values, but when I take it out (to run over all meters) all the slopes are 0 (zero).  I would simply like to run a line through a day's worth of observations (80).

I'm using Teradata v15.0.

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Comment: Where should I send the pepperoni pizza? Also, If you change your Comment to an Answer I will Accept it. Thank you so much for your speedy (and correct) answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet a Pepperoni Pizza that it's the x_axis value.

- Instead try `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY meter_id ORDER BY reading_dttm)`

This will ensure that the x_axis starts again from 1 for each meter, and each reading will always be 1 away from the previous reading on the x_axis.

This makes me thing you should probably just use `reading_dttm` as the `x_axis` value, rather than fabricating one with `ROW_NUMBER()`.  That way readings with a 5 hour gap between them have a different slope to readings with a 10 day gap between them.  You may need to convert the `reading_dttm`'s data-type, with a function like `TO_UNIXTIME(reading_dttm)`, or something similar.

I'll message you my address for the Pizza Delivery.  *(Joking.)*

Comment: Very good point about using reading_dttm as the x-axis!  Not sure why I didn't think of it myself.  This is a great early Christmas pressie.  Happy Christmas and Boxing Day!

Answer (score 1):

Additional to @MatBailie's answer.

You probably know that should you order by the timestamp instead of the `ROW_NUMBER`, but you couldn't do it because Teradata doesn't allow timestamps in this place (strange).

There's no built-in TO_UNIXTIME function in Teradata, but you can use this instead:

```
REPLACE FUNCTION TimeStamp_to_UnixTime (ts TIMESTAMP(6))
RETURNS decimal(18,6)
LANGUAGE SQL
CONTAINS SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COLLATION INVOKER
INLINE TYPE 1
RETURN 
   (Cast(ts AS DATE) - DATE '1970-01-01') * 86400
   + (Extract(HOUR From ts) * 3600)
   + (Extract(MINUTE From ts) * 60)
   + (Extract(SECOND From ts));
```

If you're not allowed to create UDFs simply cut&paste the calculation.

Comment: Vielen Dank, Frohe Weihnachten!